# Any idea how Whatsapp is backing up their chats in iCloud or how to do similar backup restore?

Tags: ios, whatsapp

I would like to know how to achieve similar backup and restore like what Whatsapp does for chat history.

***Things I have done,***

- Achieved backup and restore using iCloud but, my backup files is visible in iCloud storage. But Whatsapp does store the backup in iCloud but the backup file is not visible in iCloud storage.
- I have stored my backup file in

> Documents/My_Backup_folder/My_Backup_file.

Can anyone guide me how to make my backup file not appear in iCloud storage.

Reference / Sample code would be much appreciated.